# No name 'BlogListView' in module 'blog.views'

Tags: python, django, module

The code in the urls.py file is:

```
#blog/urls.py
    from django.urls import path
from .views import BlogListView
urlpatterns = [
    path('', BlogListView.as_view(), name='home'),
]
```

The code in views.py is :

```
#blog/views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
# Create your views here.
```

After this I get the error in urls.py that ((No name 'BlogListView' in module 'blog.views'))
I have searched for many documents but can't find the appropriate result

Comment: so you are importing BlogListView but you didn't write one?

Comment: @iklinac Thanks for the reply. I was a little confused earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `urls.py` file says that when someone visits your site, Django should look into the `blogs/views.py` file and look for a function named `BlogListView` and run that. However, that function does not exist, since you have not written it yet. This is exactly what the error message is telling you.